# AutoFac resolve interface for keyed registration

Tags: unit-testing, autofac

I am using AutoFac and am using the following lines in my registration

two different clases implement the same interface with two different keys..

```
_builder.RegisterType<CopyAppDataUserBudgetLine>().Keyed<ICopyAppData>(EntityType.UserBudgetLine).As<ICopyAppData>().InstancePerDependency();
_builder.RegisterType<CopyAppDataBudgetLine>().Keyed<ICopyAppData>(EntityType.BudgetLine).As<ICopyAppData>().InstancePerDependency();
```

same class registered with two different keys

```
_builder.RegisterType<RemoveOldAppData>().AsImplementedInterfaces().Keyed<IRemoveOldData>(EntityType.UserBudgetLine).InstancePerDependency();
_builder.RegisterType<RemoveOldAppData>().AsImplementedInterfaces().Keyed<IRemoveOldData>(EntityType.BudgetLine).InstancePerDependency();
```

Class definitions

```
public class RemoveOldAppData : RemoveAppDataBase, IRemoveOldData
    {
        public RemoveOldAppData(KonstruktEntities context, 
            ISQLQueryWhereClauseHelper sqlQueryWhereClauseHelper,
            IQueryExecutionHelper queryExecutionHelper) : base(context,sqlQueryWhereClauseHelper,queryExecutionHelper) { }
        public void RemoveBudgetLines(EntityType entityType, AccessEngine.LineAccessFilter filter)
        {
           ...
        }
    }

public class CopyAppDataBudgetLine : CopyAppDataBase , ICopyAppData
    {
        public CopyAppDataBudgetLine(KonstruktEntities context,
            ISQLQueryWhereClauseHelper sqlWhereClauseHelper,
            IQueryExecutionHelper queryExecutionHelper,
            ITableColumns columns) : base(context,sqlWhereClauseHelper,queryExecutionHelper,columns) { }

        public void CopyData(string receivingUserId, AccessEngine.LineAccessFilter queryFilter)
        {
            ...
        }
        public EntityType CopyDataEntityType
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

Here is how I try to resolve these

```
using (var scope = _container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var copyAppDataUserBudgetLine = scope.Resolve<ICopyAppData>();
    copyAppDataUserBudgetLine.CopyData("leif.andersson", filterAcccess);
```

Question: How do I resolve the above to take a specific EntityType (UserBudgetLine), do I have it in the constructor of the class or where else?

**EDIT: I got it to work by using the following:**

```
var copyAppDataUserBudgetLine = scope.ResolveKeyed<ICopyAppData>(EntityType.UserBudgetLine);
```

Is this the correct way or should I go about this differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that EntityType is some Enum that you are keying the classes on?

When I resolve Keyed Interfaces I prefer to use a custom factory that takes in the constructor an IIndex from Autofac.

When this Factory is resolved by Autofac to me Autofac will serve me essentially a dictionary of my Types and their Keys.

I would achieve this by doing something like following which I have pseudo coded from your example...

```
public Enum EntityType
{
    UserBudgetLine,
    BudgetLine
}

public class EntityCopyAppDataFactory
{
    private readonly IIndex<EntityType, ICopyAppData> _copyAppDataIndex;

    public EntityCopyAppDataFactory(IIndex<EntityType, ICopyAppData> copyAppDataIndex)
    {
        _copyAppDataIndex = copyAppDataIndex;
    }

    public ICopyAppData GetCopyAppData(EntityType entityType)
    {
        return _copyAppDataIndex[entityType];
    }
}
```

And then register this factory in Autofac

```
builder.RegisterType<EntityCopyAppDataFactory>();
```

And then I would ask for my factory from Autofac and call GetCopyAppData with EntityType.UserBudgetLine that I require, either from scope as below or by Constructor Injection at the top of my stack.

```
using (var scope = _container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var myFactory = scope.Resolve<EntityCopyAppDataFactory>();
    var copyAppDataUserBudgetLine = myFactory.GetCopyAppData(EntityType.UserBudgetLine);
}
```

I hope this gives you some food for thought about another direction perhaps rather than calling ResolveKeyed?

Comment: Thanks. Do you use these types of custom factories in all cases or only when working with keyed registrations?

Comment: I use this custom factory concept anytime I working with Keyed Registrations. You could also write something similar using an autofac registration of a Func<> to do the same job but I prefer to use a separate class for my factory to keep the code cleaner and separated.

Comment: Here is another example of using the IIndex and a good description http://nblumhardt.com/2010/08/the-iindexkv-relationship-type/

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing. This is one way to do it but I'd like to be able to always use 
`scope.Resolve` for all types of interfaces and not be forced to do `scope.ResolveKeyed` for these types of scenarios.

```
var copyAppDataUserBudgetLine = scope.ResolveKeyed<ICopyAppData>(EntityType.UserBudgetLine);
```